# Приложение вылетает, требуя FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, хотя данный флаг установлен

Tags: android

Имеется данный класс:

```
public class Share implements IShare {


@Override
public void share(List<File> data) {

    ArrayList<Uri> toShare = new ArrayList<>();
    for(File f : data){
        toShare.add(Uri.fromFile(f));
    }


    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, toShare);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent myChooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share pictures to: ");
    myChooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    MyApp.getContext().startActivity(myChooser);

    IHistoryManager hm = new HistoryManager();
    hm.addToHistory(HistoryTypes.SENT, data);
    }
}
```

В котором chooser-у устанавливается флаг FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, однако после запуска метода возникает исключение:

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

MyApp это класс, унаследованный от Application, статический метод getContext() возвращает статическую переменную с контекстом приложения:

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {
private static Context context;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переписать свой класс Application подобным образом, может поможет:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();

    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло, все равно выбрасывает исключение

Comment: вместо  .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); попробуйте    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9645975/5634351

Comment: В дебаггере оно вываливается на строке Intent myChooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share pictures to: ");, то есть не доходит до установки флагов

Comment: а что вообще вас код делает? расшаривает картинки?

Comment: да. П.С. Проблему решила пересборка проекта, он выбрасывался на строке 35 не зависимо от ее содержания :D